# Typescript overrule generic [key: string]

Tags: typescript

I have a `FormMeta` type that I use throughout my application:

```js
export type FormMeta = {
  validationSchema?: EntityValidationSchemaType;
  fields: { [fieldName: string]: FormField };
  inEditMode?: boolean;
  isDirty?: boolean;
  generalErrors?: { error: string }[];
};
```

The `fields` property of this `FormMeta` is quite vague and disables a lot of IntelliSense features which I hope to fix in some way.

Everywhere I create an object of this `FormMeta` type, I can properly fill in the `fields`:

```js
export const formMetaFilter = (): FormMeta => ({
  fields: {
    filter: { ... },
    name: { ... },
    sortBy: { ... },
  },
});
```

If I don't type this object as a `FormMeta`, TS will be able to correctly suggest all (and only) the `fields` which is awesome and exactly what I want:
[image: Proper IntelliSense]

However, other methods that expect a `FormMeta` type will not accept this untyped object, because `'filter' !== [key: string]`:
[image: Cannot match keys to generic string]

When I type the object as a `FormMeta` type, the methods will accept the object but IntelliSense breaks down for the `[key: string]` part, only providing autocompletion after the next `.`, which in turn leads to error-prone code.

**What I want to achieve:**

I'm currently using the following code:

```js
export type FormMeta<T extends string> = {
  fields: { [fieldName in T]: FormField };
  // ...
};

export const formMetaFilter = (): FormMeta<'filter' | 'name' | 'sortBy'> => ({
  fields: {
    filter: { ... },
    name: { ... },
    sortBy: { ... },
  },
});

hasEntityErrors(formMeta: FormMeta<string>): boolean { ... }
```

Which achieves all that I want: proper autocompletion, detection for unexisting fieldNames and proper `FormMeta` recognition, but it's very tedious to write and to maintain. Is there a way to let Typescript look at these more detailed key and overrule the `[key: string]` without manual hints? My `FormMeta` types can easily hold up to 50 `fields` and I use hundred of them throughout the entire codebase...

***I would like to solve this without using classes. Interfaces are allowed, though Types are still preferred.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got something which does what you are looking for by implementing a `createFormMeta` function which takes the fields separately to the rest of the metadata.

This avoids you having to write the field types manually like you did in `FormMeta<"filter" | "name" | "sortBy">`.

It's not clear to me whether this solution is acceptable for your particular use-case though.

```
type EntityValidationSchemaType = any; // not provided in the question
type FormField = any; // FormField was not provided in the question 

type FormMetaWithoutFields = {
    validationSchema?: EntityValidationSchemaType;
    inEditMode?: boolean;
    isDirty?: boolean;
    generalErrors?: { error: string }[]; 
}

type FormMeta<T extends Record<string, FormField>> = FormMetaWithoutFields & {
    fields: T;
};

const createFormMeta = <T extends Record<string, FormField>>(fields: T, meta: FormMetaWithoutFields): FormMeta<T> => {
    return { ...meta, fields };
};

// You can hover on this function and see that it automatically infers
// the return type as 
// FormMeta<{
//     fields: {
//         filter: string;
//         name: string;
//         sortBy: string;
//     };
// }>
const formMetaFilter = () => createFormMeta(
    {
        fields: {
            filter: "",
            name: "",
            sortBy: "",
        },
    },
    {} // empty metadata, but this can contain properties like `validationSchema` etc.
);

// To be implemented
declare const hasEntityErrors: <T extends Record<string, FormField>>(formMeta: FormMeta<T>) => boolean
```

Comment: Simply beautiful. It never came to my mind that I should split my types in two to make it easier to make one generic. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No problem :) Sometimes you need to get a bit creative to make Typescript happy!